# Parallel processing a set of XML files in Python

Tags: python, xml, parallel-processing

I need to process a set (~20) of relatively large (20-300MB) XML files (truncated example below) and I'm looking for a way to speed this up.

The files contain "events" (here named "datasets"), with several relevant properties, most importantly the UID. There are usually multiple events per UID.

I have a unique list of UIDs and for each of them I want to lookup the events and extract the UTCtime property. What would be the best way to parallelize this?

I've tried using threading (see below) but it didn't result in any noticeable speedup. I also tried multiprocessing, but I would need to pass the XML elements between processes, but got errors about the elements not being 'pickleable'.

Thanks

### Python approach using threading

```python
    import lxml.etree as et, threading,concurrent.futures, datetime as dt

    uidList = ['B0 2B 5C 05 09 00 12 E0',
            'B0 2A 5C 05 09 00 12 E0',
            'AD 2A 5C 05 09 00 12 E0',
            '4F 2D 5C 05 09 00 12 E0']

    uidList_split = [uidList[0:2],uidList[2:4]]

    xPathFmt = 'Dataset/[UID = "{:s}"]'
    timeFmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'

    def thread_function(i):
        scanTimes = {}
        for uid in uidList_split[i]:
            scanTimes[uid] = []
            for e in root.iterfind(xPathFmt.format(uid)):
                scanTimes[uid].append(dt.datetime.strptime(e.findtext('UTCTime'),timeFmt))
        return(scanTimes)

    tree = et.parse('test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        scanTimes = list(executor.map(thread_function, range(2)))

    scanTimes = {k: v for d in scanTimes for k, v in d.items()}

    for uid in scanTimes: print(uid,scanTimes[uid])
```

### Example XML file

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Datasets>
<Dataset>
    <UTCTime>05/31/2019 03:44:27.737</UTCTime>
    <ReaderID>44252</ReaderID>
    <Address>1</Address>
    <UID>B0 2B 5C 05 09 00 12 E0</UID>
    <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>
    <Type>177</Type>
</Dataset>
<Dataset>
    <UTCTime>05/12/2019 02:46:22.737</UTCTime>
    <ReaderID>44252</ReaderID>
    <Address>1</Address>
    <UID>B0 2B 5C 05 09 00 12 E0</UID>
    <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>
    <Type>177</Type>
</Dataset>
<Dataset>
    <UTCTime>05/31/2019 03:44:34.215</UTCTime>
    <ReaderID>44251</ReaderID>
    <Address>2</Address>
    <UID>B0 2A 5C 05 09 00 12 E0</UID>
    <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>
    <Type>177</Type>
</Dataset>
<Dataset>
    <UTCTime>05/31/2019 04:16:56.957</UTCTime>
    <ReaderID>44252</ReaderID>
    <Address>1</Address>
    <UID>AD 2A 5C 05 09 00 12 E0</UID>
    <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>
    <Type>177</Type>
</Dataset>
<Dataset>
    <UTCTime>05/31/2019 04:05:07.705</UTCTime>
    <ReaderID>44252</ReaderID>
    <Address>1</Address>
    <UID>4F 2D 5C 05 09 00 12 E0</UID>
    <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>
    <Type>177</Type>
</Dataset>
</Datasets>```
````

Comment: Curious, why do you need to parallelize? The quantity and size of files do not seem too large.

Comment: On my system it's going very slow. For the biggest file (~300MB), searching for a specific UID using XPath takes about 20 seconds. I have well over a thousand UIDs. Perhaps I'm just doing it in an inefficient way?

Comment: You've gone very quiet... no feedback?

Answer (score 1):

I figure if you are doing lots of lookups, e.g. thousands as you say, you should spend some time getting the data into a better structure for searching. So, I am suggesting parsing the XML into an *"in-memory"* data-structure and then doing lookups from memory. You may think it will take too much RAM, but if you look at a typical dataset entry in your XML file, you will see it has around 220 bytes, whereas you only really want around 30 bytes of UTCTime and UID, so it is going to be around 7x smaller.

I came up with 2 methods...

The first one uses `xmltodict` and loads the XML file into a Python `dict`. It takes around 18 seconds to load a 200MB dummy XML file on my Mac, but then subsequent lookups take just 3 microseconds each. Its advantages are that it is a standard, tested XML reader so it should be robust, but it stores stuff you probably don't need so is heavier on memory.

The second method just parses the XML with Python regexes. It is about the same speed, but takes less memory but is maybe less robust.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def method1():

    import xmltodict

    with open('file.xml') as fd:
        XML = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

    # Lookup a UID
    for Dataset in XML['Datasets']['Dataset']:
        if Dataset['UID'] == "31 1e 24 81 82 71 6f 1d":
            print(Dataset)

def method2():

    import re

    # Compile the regex to look for UID and UTCTime for better performance
    UIDre     = re.compile("<UID>(.*)</UID>")
    UTCTimere = re.compile("<UTCTime>(.*)</UTCTime>")

    # Parse XML building a dict, indexed by UID, of lists of matching times
    d = {}
    with open('file.xml') as fp:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(fp):
            result = re.search(UIDre,line)
            if result != None:
                UID = result.group(1)
                #print(f"UID:{UID}")
                if not UID in d:
                    d[UID] = []
                d[UID].append(UTCTime)
                continue
            result = re.search(UTCTimere,line)
            if result != None:
                UTCTime = result.group(1)
                #print(f"UTCTime:{UTCTime}")

    # Do a lookup
    print(d["31 1e 24 81 82 71 6f 1d"])

method1()
method2()
```

---

In case anyone else fancy testing theories or methods, here is the code I used to generate a 200MB XML file with 1,000,000 dummy datasets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>')
print('<Datasets>')
for d in range(1000000):
    ReaderID = random.randrange(65536)
    UID = "%02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)
    UID+= " %02x" % random.randrange(256)

    Type = random.randrange(65536)
    print(f"<Dataset>")
    print(f"   <UTCTime>05/31/2019 04:05:07.705</UTCTime>")
    print(f"   <ReaderID>{ReaderID}</ReaderID>")
    print(f"   <Address>1</Address>")
    print(f"   <UID>{UID}</UID>")
    print(f"   <ScanCount>1</ScanCount>")
    print(f"   <Type>{Type}</Type>")
    print(f"</Dataset>")

print('</Datasets>')
```

I then manually seeded the UID in my code into the XML file using a regular editor for test purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Perhaps I'm just doing it in an inefficient way?*

Yes, this is the root-cause.

**1st)** the problem-approach is **not** working as a True-**`[PARALLEL]`** computing, but as a *"just"*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** class-of-process scheduling. Either worker may finish its work independently of any other one. This is not a True-`[PARALLEL]` flow of processing.

**2nd)** the use of python threads-based tools ( since ever, till 3.7 ) **has never** brought any efficient amount of `[CONCURRENT]`-computing, because of the internal python behaviour of the GIL-interpreter-LOCK.

All, and best repeat this in all caps **ALL THREADS** inside the python interpreter sit and wait until they in a round-robin-fashion acquire the ownership of a singleton instance, called **GIL-lock** (simplified for brevity), and do nothing useful on waiting.

That means, all threads wait, one (the one, now having POSACK'ed GIL-lock ownership) can do some small amount of computing, before it stops doing that and signals the python to have released the GIL-lock ownership that others try to gain next.

This effectively re-**`[SERIAL]`**-ises any work one has loaded on a pool of python threads into one-and-only-one pure-**[SERIAL]**-sequence of operations, interleaved with small amounts of time, spent above the useful-job scope, during the fights for the GIL-lock acquisition and release.

The GIL-lock monopoly for orchestrating a pure-[SERIAL] flow of work is intentional since ever in the design of the python interpreter. This "strategy" avoids any **`[CONCURRENT]`**-operation from ever taking place. **Principally.**

This means one gains adverse only speedup effects (more time spent for the equal work executed) from threads-based computing in python, **unless the use-case** was accompanied with such amount of "immense" GUI/disk/network-I/O latencies, that may get masked by the interleaving the thread's computing progress by a round-robin stepping of all the threads through the central GIL-lock dancing ball-room. **Never ever elsewhere else.**

---

### Last, but not least :

Your iteration strategy seems to be devastatingly wrong either. Scanning the same file as-many-times top-to-bottom as there are items in outer control-list is anywhere near the cost-effective strategy:

```
def thread_function(i): ############## PERFORMANCE-WISE ANTI-PATTERN [DO NOT DO]
        scanTimes = {}               #-- set empty dict{}
        for uid in uidList_split[i]: #-- len(uidList_split[i])-times re-run (!!!!)
            scanTimes[uid] = []      #-- add an empty []     # for next uid
            for e in root.iterfind(xPathFmt.format(uid)):    # each time start
                scanTimes[uid].append(dt.datetime.strptime(  #     from root.
                e.findtext( 'UTCTime' ), timeFmt            )#    .iterfind()
                                       )                     #     again and again
        return(scanTimes)
```

Way better gets to iterate once-and-only once over the slowest resource ( the disk-file-I/O ) and test each found `xPathNonUIDspecifitFmtTEMPLATE` for its UID-match against a `uidList_split`-list ( at a cost way, way cheaper, than re-iterating an expensive, disk-file-I/O dependent ( yet, static ) file more than once. Appending a variable ad-hoc found UID is as easy as:

```
  if uid2seek not in scanTimes.keys():
                     scanTimes[uid2seek] = [ ..., ] # add a not yet found UID
     else:
                     scanTimes[uid2seek].append(...)# for already "visited" UID(s)
```